# How to prepopulate test data in protractor based tests?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am writing end-to-end test for my angularjs app using protractor. As its e-2-e test, so I plan to perform db based tasks too on server side, hence rejecting mocking of data. So I need to pre-populate the test data in backend db.
How can I achieve this in protractor?

Any input would be of great help.

Comment: I put tests to the continuous integration and added 1 additional before step which generates necessary back end data. I thing you probably could achieve that using plain JavaScript in onPrepare block or something like this, but it depends on requirements

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Would look into it

Answer (score 0):

I use Node.js to get some data, that I will need for the test. The data is saved via setter. Protractor tests use it via the getter.
All I need is just to require the script, so it runs; there is no need to import/export values explicitly.

```
//1st file - ./inc/data.js
var request = require('request')
var getterSetter = require('./path_to_file.js')
request.get('http//.....',function(data){
getterSetter.set(data)
}
```

So the first file obtain some data and the data is in *getterSetter*. Now I just require the file, without using it, just to invoke the actions in *data.js*

```
//2nd file - test.js
var startItUp = require('./inc/data.js')
var getterSetter = require('./path_to_file.js')
describe('test',function(){
browser.get(getterSetter.get()); // finally we use the prepared data
browser.waitForAngular(); 
}
```